# Failed to construct transformer: Error: Cannot parse C:

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

After a hard drive crash, I got a new one, reloaded my window Os, and copied my react native project folder. But after setting up my environment, I ran `npm install` and it was successful, but when I tried to run my project to my devices as usual I got the following error on my node terminal

`Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot parse C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\asynclayoutinflater\package.json as JSON: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:167:15) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:78:24) at _next (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:98:9) at C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:103:7 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:95:12) at Object.worker (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:120:18) at execFunction (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:155:17) at execHelper (C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:139:5) { type: 'Error' }`

And here is the log in my terminal after running the command `npx react-native run-android` I got the following error

`C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\android\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\androidx\activity\R$attr_1.class: D8: Invalid classfile header

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> There were multiple failures while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform$DexConversionWorkAction
> > Failed to process C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\android\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform$DexConversionWorkAction
> > Failed to process C:\Users\BEN\Documents\xx\android\app\build\intermediates\javac\debug\classes

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Error while merging dex archives:

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15m 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run
CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.`

How can I solve these issues? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following things.

First delete the build folder, that might be causing the issue.

```
\android\app\build\
```

after deleting the directory try for build again.

If this also doesn't work , go to

```
cd android
./gradlew cache clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

also in the end you can try by changing gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties to a newer one.